# How String.count() works?

Tags: python

I am new to python and learning. As given [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm) `count()` method when used on strings gives the number of occurrences of sub string in a string.

So when i Do :

`'BANANA'.count('ANA')`

Expected output should be 2 as 'ANA' occurs twice in 'BANANA' but `count` returns 1.

Can someone please explain this, or maybe i have misunderstood something.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Non overlap? Try reading the documentation?

Comment: the second `A` in the first occurence of `ANA` is not reused

Comment: You can find the source code here: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objeshort, it only returns the count for unique occurrences of non-overlapping strings.

Comment: @Jaco The [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython) is now on GitHub.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> help(str.count)
Help on method_descriptor:

count(...)
    S.count(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in
    string S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are
    interpreted as in slice notation.
```

Notice the **non-overlapping**.

Comment: is there any way to count overlapping ?

Comment: Have a look at regular expressions, as suggessted by Philipp.

Answer (score 6):

You can use regular expressions to find it. Use the function *findall* from module *re* to find overlapping occurences

```
import re
len(re.findall('(?=ANA)', 'BANANA'))
```

which yields 2.

Or yields 3 here:

```
import re
len(re.findall('(?=ANA)', 'BANANAANA'))
```

Comment: is there any easy way to do this without using a library ?

Comment: You cannot load libraries? That the point of python. And re is surely no exotic library.

Comment: Also `re` is part of the standard library so it's not like "using a library" in my opinion (at least not like using an external library).

Comment: @AngryCoder `re` is packaged with python so you just sticking an `import` statement in is not bother

Comment: @AngryCoder Sure, you could use the `.find` method in a loop, but doing that's a bit messy compared to using the standard `re` module, since you need to keep track of the `start` arg you pass to `.find`.