# Please help me why the String.count() incorrect? [Python 3.x]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an exercise that find how many time a sub string appear in a main string.

2 inputs are main string and sub string.

I used string.count() but with the main string "abcdcdc" and sub string "cdc", the result only 1 why you can see the sub string "cdc" appeared twice time "ab**cdc**dc" & "abcd**cdc**".

So that I would like to know why my code provided incorrect result.
Does the string.count() on calculate one time for each apperance?
Hereunder is my code:

```
 strs=str(input())
 sub_str=str(input())

print(strs.count(sub_str))
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: [str.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) — "Return the number of **non-overlapping** occurrences"

Answer (score 0):

Please see 
[How String.count() works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368751/how-string-count-works)

count() only counts non-overlapping substrings.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here: [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)

> Return the number of **non-overlapping** occurrences of substring

The two occurrences in your example overlap. The number of non-overlapping occurrences is one.